# Quickaction bar on android google map marker

Tags: android

You guys probably heard of the quick action bar which is really great for user interaction. But I can't find the way to show the quick action bar when user tap on the marker on android's google maps.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GreenDroid](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction) is help full. with example of QuickAction bar.

Answer (score 2):

In `onTap()` create desired number of `ActionItem` s set some attributes like `setTitle("Title");` `setDrawable(resource)`; then create `QuickAction` object to add all created `ActionItem`s. And `override` the `onActionItemClickedListener()` to do operation for each specific `ActionItem`. Is this what you want? And for the showing did you tried `QAobj.show();` at the end?

Comment: The problem is QAObj.show(View anchor) requires a view. And i can't find the view anywhere inside onTap function :(

Comment: public boolean onTap(GeoPoint arg0, MapView arg1) ? or you are using ItemizedOverlay? 

If you dont, then the MapView will be your view argument.

Comment: I am using a class that extend ItemizedOverlay and my override method is onTap(int index). Is there a onTap(int index, GeoPoint arg0,MapView arg1) method for me to use?
Furthermore I want my action bar to appear on the position of the marker. if i put map view in QAObj.show(mapview), the quick action bar will show at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Hmm... use Rect to find the center of the screen/use the mapcontroller to move to center to that marker and get the view . I cant think of anything else..

or try passing this `arg1.getChildAt(index)` it returns the child view in your case the marker