# How to add the Action bar in android 2.3 platform?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application i want to create an action bar which as my application icon and a view control. I refered so many tutorials and samples to create action bar but all of them have a plenty of code. I have also read the ActionBarSherlock but this need minsdkversion 15 to compile the libraries. Because i am new in android therefore i need a step by step tutorial to create a simple action bar. 
If you know a simple and easy tutorial to create action bar using xml then please post your answer.

Comment: http://actionbarsherlock.com/ using this lib ....

Comment: did you gone thru this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: action bar sherlock is actually working on api level BELOW android 3.0 (level 11)

Comment: I saw the viedeo tutorial to implement the sherlock in android app. In this tutorial first he implement the sherlock application (implement on 4.0)and then attach that application to the application which havs api level below 3.0.

Comment: I saw that tutorial in sherlock official website.

Comment: @padma I have gone thru that also but in android 2.3 there is not any reference to android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText".

Comment: "I have also read the ActionBarSherlock but this need minsdkversion 15 to compile the libraries." -- no, you do not. You need your **build target** to be API Level 14 or higher. Your `android:minSdkVersion` can be anything 7 or higher.

Comment: I also saw the tutorial on sherlock official site that how can we use the sherlock libraries? I think i have misunderstood something. Can you guide me with steps to implement the sherlock in my app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Action Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214012/android-action-bar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used this library for adding an action bar to 2.2+ apps:

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar

I found it easy to use and visually appealing, although the style of it does not exactly match the default action bar in ICS.

Comment: Now my application is installed in the emulator but my app icon doesn't show on my emulator home screen. I followed the example of actionbar given in  https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar and used this example in my application. But in this example there is no activity in the AndroidManifest xml file and one thing also In this example package name is com.markupartist.android.widget.actionbar so i want to know that should i put my all Activity files in that package or not.

Comment: and please tell me that what is the use of this line            import com.markupartist.android.widget.actionbar.R;                           In actionbar.java

Comment: @NaveenChauhan I don't believe that apps appear on the home screen by default, have you checked the app launcher?

Comment: @NaveenChauhan the import statement refers to the ActionBar library projects resources, such as drawables and XML layout files. Importing it allows the code to refer to resources easily, e.g. `setContentView(R.layout.myLayout)`

Comment: should i add the action bar project as a library project ? There is also a project actionbarexample. Should i use the actionbar project directory as a library project and use the actionbarexample project as my app project?

Comment: When i downloaded the zip file from https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar, It has two directory actionbar and actionbarexample. Should i use actionbar project as a library project and actionbarexample as my application?

Comment: Add actionbar as a library project of your project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11922/discussion-between-naveen-chauhan-and-ian-newson)

Comment: Finally i done it. But still i want to know something from you. Will it work with my phone which has android 2.3 platform?

Comment: Because it uses android 4.3 to compile the application.

Comment: There is two apk file actionbar.apk and HomeActivity.apk. actionbar.apk is of library project and HomeActivity.apk is of my application. Which one should i install in my phone so the it works as same as my emulator screen?

Comment: Yes, it will work with Android 2.3. I think HomeActivity.apk is the one you should install.

Comment: Is there any other method to create actionbar for android 2.3 platform?

Comment: I have done this and also tested in in android 10 level successfully. Now I start to make my project by adding actionbar project as a library project and copy all files from actionbarexample directory to my project. I found no error when i use actionbar class in my project("KeepInTouch"). But when i start to run it on android 4.0.3 emulator i found an error in console.       Could not find KeepInTouch.apk!                                         I have also clean and rebuild my project but my problem remain same. Do you know why i am getting this error ?

Answer (score 2):

**Read this tutorial from Android's official site.**
[image: Action Bar Android]
You just need to include `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` support jar in your project from your `android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs` path on your disk. Then you can use ActionBar below API 11 in Android.

**Official Android Tutorial is here:** [Action Bar Android Official](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) Sherlock bar was creating issues for me then I got this solution.