# android 2.3.3 api 10 action bar

Tags: android

I'm using android 2.3.3(on eclipse), I would like to add action bar to my project.

I've tried to add android support library V7 and got many errors like this:

> [2013-08-12 16:42:36 - app name_1_1_1] C:\Program
>   Files\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:24:
>   error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.

Is it possible to add the support library or add different library for the action bar ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Action Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214012/android-action-bar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Read this tutorial from Android's official site.**
[image: Action Bar Android]
You just need to include `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` support jar in your project from your `android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs` path on your disk. Then you can use ActionBar below API 11 in Android.

**Official Android Tutorial is here:** [Action Bar Android Official](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) Sherlock bar was creating issues for me then I got this solution.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you

[Android actionbar how to add supporting library v7 appcompat for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903521/android-actionbar-how-to-add-supporting-library-v7-appcompat)

or try [this](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/) one

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to go to do `ActionBar` for `Android 2.3.3/API Level 10`,

1. You can use `ActionBarCombat` which is the support library version
   of `Android`; here is a detailed official tutorial
   http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html
2. You can use 3rd party library which is `ActionBarSherlock`, also the
   usage is here http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). From their website:

> The library will automatically use the native action bar when appropriate or will automatically wrap a custom implementation around your layouts. This allows you to easily develop an application with an action bar for every version of Android from 2.x and up.

Answer (score 0):

its because you set project build target below 4.0

try to change ur build target above 4.0

and don;'t worry,, it can run on 2.3.3 too